# Why deleting a row from one table leads to change of id in another?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

SOLVED! I want to implement deleting a product from a customer's cart. I have tables customers, shopping_cart, cart_item. And similar Java classes. When delete button is pressed, the item from shoppingCart.cartItems is deleted, but when row from cartItem is deleted, customer_id and shopping_cart_id increase by one.

```
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private Long id;

    ...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer")
    private ShoppingCart shoppingCart;
}
```

```
public class ShoppingCart {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "shopping_cart_id")
    private Long id;

    ...

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "cart")
    private Set<CartItem> cartItem;

}
```

```
public class CartItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cart_item_id")
    private Long id;

    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "shopping_cart_id", referencedColumnName = "shopping_cart_id")
    private ShoppingCart cart;

}
```

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update-cart", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "action=delete")
    public String deleteItemFromCart(@RequestParam("id") Long productId,
                                     Model model,
                                     Principal principal){
        if(principal == null){
            return "redirect:/login";
        }else{
            String username = principal.getName();
            Customer customer = customerService.findByUsername(username);
            Product product = productService.getProductById(productId);
            ShoppingCart cart = cartService.deleteItemFromCart(product, customer);
            model.addAttribute("shoppingCart", cart);
            return "redirect:/cart";
        }

    }
```

```
@Override
    public ShoppingCart deleteItemFromCart(Product product, Customer customer) {
        ShoppingCart cart = customer.getShoppingCart();
        Set<CartItem> cartItems = cart.getCartItem();
        CartItem item = findCartItem(cartItems, product.getId());
        cartItems.remove(item);

        double totalPrice = totalPrice(cartItems);
        int totalItems = totalItems(cartItems);

        cart.setCartItem(cartItems);
        cart.setTotalItems(totalItems);
        cart.setTotalPrices(totalPrice);
        itemRepository.delete(item);

        return cartRepository.save(cart);
    }
```

Tables dont have triggers [schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH9lv.jpg)

UPD: I have solved my issue by removing cascade = CascadeType.ALL above ShoppingCart field from CartItem class and above Customer field from ShoppingCart class. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a database trigger on that table? Maybe it causes what you described.

Comment: Hi. How can i check it?

Comment: I don't use MySQL so I don't know which data dictionary view you'd query (manually). But, if you use some GUI, I presume that - if you navigate to that table, there's a tab which shows triggers related to that table, or (at least) **script** used to create table and all other objects (indexes, constraints, triggers ...) related to it. So, if you do use such a GUI, have a look.

Comment: It doesnt have any triggers, i just checked in workbench

Comment: OK; then trigger isn't to blame.  I don't have any other ideas (especially regarding tools you use) so I can just hope that someone else will be able to assist.